# Why cursor goes to next line while printing a file of one line?

Tags: c, file, io, cursor, printf

I have below C program to print the content of a file and to count total number of characters in it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /*Declaring a FILE pointer fp.*/
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    int noc = 0;

    /*Using fopen() to get the address of the FILE structure, and store it in fp*/
    fp = fopen("poem.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
            printf("Error opening file");
            exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
            ch = fgetc(fp);
            if (ch == EOF) /* EOF will be there at the end of the file.*/
                    break;
            noc++;
            printf("%c",ch); /* Printing the content of the file character by character*/
    }

    //printf("\n");

    close(fp); /* We need to fclose() the fp, because we have fopen()ed */

    printf("\tNumber of characters: %d\n",noc);

    return 0;
}

/*One interesting observation: There is an extra new line printed. Why ???*/
```

File poem.txt has just one line. Below is content of poem.txt

**It starts with the end.**

I have not hit ENTER while writing this file so it is only of one line.

```
-bash-4.1$ wc poem.txt
 1  5 24 poem.txt
-bash-4.1$
```

You can see this is confirmed by wc (Howevr I still dont understand why wc gives number of characters as 24, instead of 23).

Below is the output of this program.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
It starts with the end.
     Number of characters in this file: 24
-bash-4.1$
```

You can see that after printing all the characters of the file, the cursor is taken to the next line even though I have commented the printf("\n") after printing all the characters of the file .

Why is the cursor taken to new line? I was expecting cursor to be in the same line after printing all the characters of the file, hence used a \t in the next printf.

Also you see that my program says that number of characters is 24 (which is inline with "wc poem.txt" output).

So I am confused why is the cursor taken to new line after printing last character of the file ? Also why is total number of characters (noc) 24 and not 23 ?

P.S. Although I have same question for the number of characters shown by "wc" you can ignore the "wc" outout except the number if lines. I may probably post a next question for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Print every character as an ascii value and see what is the code of the last character :) (using `printf("%d ",ch);`)

Comment: @JanLegner Yea I did that, it prints 24 numbers (to my surprise) , and that last number is 10 (newline). But why is there this new line when while writing this file i DID NOT hit ENTER. Its only one line !!!

Comment: You have no guarantee that your text editor did not add any newline to the end of your file... try creating it with `echo It starts with the end.>outputFile.txt` and with `echo -n It starts with the end.>outputFile.txt` and see the difference

Comment: @JanLegner Oh so vi is adding that \n in the end. I typed this in vi editor. I tried those two echo and echo -n, now i see the difference. I will next create a file with C-program and not put any \n . Hopefully my doubts will clear then. I will update here.

Comment: @JanLegner Confirmed !! vi editor was adding the new line. I created a file using a C program and put no \n in it. Now both "wc" and my program above do not show a new line. Thanks much.

Comment: Glad I helped. But remember that it is not a bad thing to have a newline at the end of your file - if you read input line by line with some function that expects newline as a separator (obviously) it comes handy if even your last line is terminated by `'\n'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the cursor taken to new line?

- Because the `'\n'` character is in the file.

> Also you see that my program says that number of characters is 24 (which is inline with "wc poem.txt" output).

- Because the 23 characters that were printed plus the `'\n'` are all in the file.

You can try to escape the whitespace characters to see them, since they are invisible, so something like this

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    noc++;
    if (isspace(ch) != 0)
        printf("\\%02X", ch);
    else
        printf("%c", ch);
}
```

this way you will see each character, you will need to include `<ctype.h>`

**Note**: using `break` is IMHO only needed in very special situations, I don't like it because it makes hard to follow the program flow.

Comment: Yes I did what you suggested, and it prints 24 1's. But basically that is exactly my question. Where did the \n come from (the 24th character) ?

Comment: Looks like vi editor is adding the \n . Also thanks for suggesting to use break more carefully. I will next create a file with a C code and not put any \n . Then i guess all my doubts will be clear.

Comment: Confirmed !! vi editor was adding the new line. I created a file using a C program and put no \n in it. Now both "wc" and my program above do not show a new line. Thanks much.